# ListView not showing items

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to display a basic array of titles in a list view using fragments. And just not able to get the List items to show up. Wondering if anyone can shed some light. Also are there any good resources that help you understand Layouts well?

Here is my list_fragment.xml and the listfragment source file

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <ListView 
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

public class PublicTradeListFragment extends ListFragment 
{
    private String trades[];

    public PublicTradeListFragment()
    {
        trades = new String [] {
                "Trade ?",
                "Give up ?",
                "Trade again?"
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,trades);
        setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment,container,false);
    }

    @Override
     public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id) {

      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
}
```

[image: list shows nothing]

[image: Hierarchy view shows a frame layout instead of a LinearLayout]

Comment: try setting the adapter in `onActivityCreated`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in "on Create View" then 
"return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);"

Check this link: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/a-listfragment-application-in-android/

Comment: I think my issue probably has to do with the layout height,width parameters. I tried the solutions you and raghunandan suggested, with no luck.

Comment: Since you are using only 1 view you can try removing "layout_weight" option & change "layout_height" as "wrap_content"

Comment: still the same issue. :(